# How do I replace the sign depending on what it is in the string?

Tags: c#, .net, math, ocr

```
var Ocr = new IronTesseract(); 
string? path = Console.ReadLine();
string[] Signs = {"+", "-"}; 
using (var Input = new OcrInput(path))
{
  var Result = Ocr.Read(Input);
  if (Result.Text.Contains('+') || Result.Text.Contains('-'))
  {
    Console.Clear(); 
    string TrimmedResult = Result.Text.Trim(); 
    string FirstNumber = TrimmedResult.Split(/*I want the sign here to be the one in Result.Text */ ).Last();
    int FirstTrimmed = Convert.ToInt32(FirstNumber.Trim()); 
    Console.WriteLine(FirstTrimmed + " is the first number.");
    string SecondNumber = TrimmedResult.Split(/*I want the sign here to be the one in Result.Text */ ).Last();
    int SecondTrimmed = Convert.ToInt32(SecondNumber.Trim()); 
    Console.WriteLine(SecondTrimmed + " is the second number.");
    int ResultMath = FirstTrimmed /*I want the sign here to be the one in Result.Text */ SecondTrimmed; 
    Console.WriteLine(ResultMath); 
  }
  
  Console.ReadKey(); 
}
```

Instead of using two if statements depending on which sign is in the Result.Text string, I want to use one if statement where the sign is interchangeable. How do I do it? I'm lost

Comment: It would be longer, but you could try a tertiary statement. They generally are: ```Equality statement ? true : false``` so something like ```(Result.Text.Contains('+') ? "+" : "-")``` in your commented section. The issue you face is if the results contain both a + and -.

Comment: The code in the post has only *one `if` statement*... Did you paste a wrong example in the question? (or maybe "Instead of using *two if statements*..." means something different for you)

Comment: No, this is the code I'm working on. I want it to have one if statement where the signs change in FirstNumber, SecondNumber and ResultMath depending on whether Result.Text has a + or a minus. Sorry about the unclarity @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: For some reason, can't edit my comment, so here is the link for tertiary in c#. Look specifically at the conditionality with if at the bottom. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: Do i understand you correctly, that in the last line `int ResultMath = FirstTrimmed ...` you want to exercise an actual addition or subtraction depending on the sign you found in the string?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @AhmedSherif you obviously know that there are plenty of existing ways to "evaluate math expression"... Can you please clarify what is the reason of attempting to write your own? (as this will lead to very different answers - including code-generation approaches you current code hints as - since you obviously can't add operator as a string to compiled code - probably you are looking for Expression Trees)

Comment: Use combination of two inline-if's (ternary operators) again, like (pseudo-code): `int ResultMath = (Result.Text.Contains('+')) ? a + b : (Result.Text.Contains('-')) ? a - b : 0`. If you don't find this readable, use normal `if` instead. There is no reason trying to avoid or reduce `if` statements if it leads to code that is _less_ readable.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm trying to get text from a photo, store that text into a string, then convert the numbers before and after the sign into their own integers, I was stuck at that part but using tertiary statements worked. Then I want to get both integers and either add or subtract them depending on the sign that is present in the Result.Text string. I'm not sure if I'm taking the right approach to this personally

Comment: Just an FYI: Don't say "tertiary statements" or "tertiary operator" That's not what it is called. It's called [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator), or if you are lazy-mouthed like me just [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace That makes sense. I thought there would be an easier approach to this and thought it would be a good practice making my code smaller and potentially easier to read. Didn't work out very well though haha